# Buffer with five elements Java

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the best way to create some construction with exactly five elements and when I try to put another one to remove the firstone etc ?

Comment: Where ? When ? What ? Which Element ?

Comment: Elements should be simple double values

Comment: And why can't you do it?

Comment: Use a List and prevent the maximum length from exceeding 5.

Comment: Im wonderoing what construction should I use ? ArrayList or HashMap witch is the best way to handle it ?

Comment: Any of the lists would do (probably an arraylist) or an array itself. Then wrap it in an object that performs the function you desire

Comment: people keep complaining that we are rude, but there you go. What can we  understand from this question? We need a "Mind reading" functionality in this site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Ring Buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi 6 answers, still counting :)

Comment: You want a FIFO structure of at most ( elements. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580457/fifo-class-in-java

Comment: Try LinkedHashMap with overriding removeEldestEntry method.

Answer (score 1):

I would just recommend you an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
It is very easy to Handle and the Remove/Add Operations are available

Answer (score 0):

[Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is the LIFO object you need.

- If you are a Apache fan, you have [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html)
- If you are more into Guava, you have [EvictingQueue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.java)
- You can also do it yourself: (LinkedList is one implementation amongst others)

`

```
// Create
Queue q = new LinkedList();

// Insert 
void safeInsert(Queue q, Object elt) {
  if (q.size()>=5) {
    q.poll();
  }
  q.offer(elt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) provided by Apache Commons Collections does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called a **circular buffer** or **ring buffer**.

The Java library [does not provide an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325602/what-is-the-best-resizable-circular-byte-buffer-available-in-java) for you ([confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java), [confirmed again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer)), so you will have to [write one yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp), or use a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the "best solution", but it's quite simple and does exactly what you want:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
...

list.add(item);
if(list.size()>5){
 list.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<Object>{

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5;

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Object object) {

        if(this.size() == MAX_SIZE)
            this.remove(0);
        super.add(MAX_SIZE -1, object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object object) {

        if(this.size() == MAX_SIZE)
            this.remove(0);
        return super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Object> collection) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Object> collection) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }

}
```